# Console log not getting detailed logs with Serilog but text file log works

Tags: asp.net-core, stdout, serilog

Added following code in `Program.cs` file inside `main()` method:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
             .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")
             .Build();

        string Region = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("REGION");
        Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
            .ReadFrom.Configuration(configuration)
            .Enrich.WithProperty("x.region", $"{Region}")                
            .CreateLogger();

        try
        {
            Log.Information("Application is boot");
            CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Log.Fatal(ex, "Application Failed to boot");
        }
        finally
        {
            Log.CloseAndFlush();
        }
    }
```

Added below middleware on the `configure()` method in `startup.cs`:

```
app.UseSerilogRequestLogging();
```

Added following codes in `appsettings.json`:

```
"ApplicationName": "TestService",
"AllowedHosts": "*",
"Serilog": {
"Using": [],
"MinimumLevel": "Information",
"Override": {
  "Microsoft": "Warning",
  "System": "Warning"
},
"Enrich": [ "FromLogContext", "withMachineName" ],
"WriteTo": [
  {
    "Name": "Console"
  }
]
}
```

This is what I am getting on Output window (View -> Output) and Intermediate window.

[image]

[image]

It's not showing detailed error message. Is it the right place to check the error logs for stdout or is there something I missed in the code for this implementation? Could you please help?

Comment: Your configuration looks fine at a glance. You should not worry about logs/errors in Debug output. Most of the time they are internal stuff. Real problems will be showed in sinks to which your error logs will be written, in your case, the console. So, if there are no errors in console, it's all okay. To see how an error will be looking in console, force one with `Log.Error("Error message")` pasted _before_ the try-catch block.

Answer (score 1):

```
{
  "Serilog": {
"WriteTo": [{"Name": "Console"}]
  }
 }
```

This is the configuration for console logging provided on GitHub. And the image is the debug logs, console logs displays on the application output cmd window. So you are checking in wrong place.

Comment: Can I know how to get this application output cmd window. I am running my application in visual studio

Comment: From your project properties set output to exe